# duplicate vue 3 app after using vite to build

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite

Hitting a super bizarre issue with my vue3 application.

- Everything works correctly when running `yarn dev / vite`
- Everything works correctly when running `yarn preview / vite preview`
- Building works correctly, but once deployed/running the browser the built version instantiates the vue app twice, in the console it shows duplicate messages and has 2 different versions of the index file, one prefixed with VM420...

[image]

My `vite.config.js` looks like this:

```
import { defineConfig, SharedConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
const path = require('path')



// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    resolve: {
        dedupe: ['vue'],
        alias: {
            // 'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
            vue: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'vue', 'dist', 'vue.esm-bundler.js'),
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
        },
    },
    server: {
        port: 4002,
    },
    plugins: [
        vue(),
    ],
    build: {
        sourcemap: true,
    },
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                additionalData: `@import "./src/styles/variables";`
            },
        },
    },
})
```